# Excess 401k deferral: which account?

Tags: united-states, 401k, irs, excess-contribution

I switched jobs in the middle of 2019 and hence have multiple pretax 401k accounts (traditional). I have excessive deferral when I combine my contributions to both accounts (14k to each account) and I am planning to let them remain in the current status (willing to pay tax twice).

I was wondering which account is considered to hold the excess deferral — first or second one, or either of them?